# Do you need additional Security Products besides Forefront Security For Exchange Server

Tags: spam, exchange-2010, anti-virus, microsoft-forefront

Does Forefront for Exchange Server 2010 cover the entire windows server or just the Exchange 2010 installation on a Windows 2008 R2 server? Do we need to run an additional Forefront product for full protection on the Windows server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForeFront for Exchange 2010 does not protect the operating system from evil, just Exchange itself. You should run the same ForeFront package you're running on your other servers. Just be sure to add the Exchange directories to the Do Not Scan list.

Comment: Thank you. I found this article on which files/directories/processes need to be excluded when doing so. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332342.aspx