# Forefront Client Security On Server with Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, anti-virus, microsoft-forefront

If we install Forefront Client Security on a Server which already has Forefront for Exchange 2010 is it smart enough to exclude all of the exchange directories/process/file extensions as suggested by this technet article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332342.aspx?

The configuration if it doesn't seems daunting.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to check the docs but in general, no - the generic install doesn't know what to exclude for Exchange.   I generally leave it to the Exchange install.  The server should be pretty well hardened already.  I wouldn't double up.

Comment: This advice seems to contradict the answer on this post? http://serverfault.com/questions/189067/do-you-need-additional-security-products-besides-forefront-security-for-exchange

Comment: I'd recommend his advice over mine, in general.  Though I've never had a virus get through to my Exchange servers, and I don't personally prefer to run OS AV on them.